# copy and paste in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with Excel VBA coding.

I want to make one coding may copy data from one sheet to a sheet with certain conditions. my data in the form binary.

data in sheet1 has nearly a thousand row. I just want to take 15 random row of data from sheet1 to sheet 2. The criteria which must be fulfilled is that each column only has the sum of the column is 3. if not met, other data will be taken.

[here the example of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg0ke.jpg)

when i click generate. it will copy from data sheet 1 to sheet 2. i want my data copy like the red circle one. not like the red column one. please help me

```
Option Explicit
Sub Random20()
Randomize
Dim MyRows() As Integer    
Dim numRows, percRows, nxtRow, nxtRnd, chkRnd, copyRow As Integer
'Determine Number of Rows in Sheet1 Column A
  numRows = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   percRows = 17

    ReDim MyRows(percRows) 
'Create Random numbers and fill array
     For nxtRow = 1 To percRows
getNew:
'Generate Random number
      nxtRnd = Int((numRows) * Rnd + 1)
'Loop through array, checking for Duplicates
       For chkRnd = 1 To nxtRow
'Get new number if Duplicate is found
        If MyRows(chkRnd) = nxtRnd Then GoTo getNew
       Next
'Add element if Random number is unique
      MyRows(nxtRow) = nxtRnd
     Next
'Loop through Array, copying rows to Sheet2
  For copyRow = 1 To percRows
   Sheets(1).Rows(MyRows(copyRow)).EntireRow.Copy _
     Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(copyRow, 1)
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Show us any code you have written so far so that we can help. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: Do you want all columns to total 3? or any single column? How many columns of data do you have for each row? All i can think of would be a mentally long formula to work it out with a dual  for next loop that checks each column total..

Comment: If it's a single column of data then I would `Dim ClmTtl As Integer` and start a 'for' 'next' loop like you have but before the loop `ClmTtl = 0` then loop through each row number adding the value of each cell from that column to `ClmTtl`. After the loop you can then do an if to see if the value = 3 and if not either `goto` an earlier stage in the code or call the sub again to restart it.

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor yeahh. i want all column total 3. can you show me the code. ?

Comment: Well, it's certainly achievable but for multiple columns the code would be working extremely hard and if the answer isn't there it could potentially loop endlessly. To keep the code entirely random the majority of outcomes will not be 3 in every column so will fail and begin again so does it have to be entirely random or could you factor in some assisted code like if total of column is now 3 then filter remaining results to 0 and search special cells instead? just a though as teh code would execute faster...

Comment: I mocked up the RAND function on a spreadsheet and had a macro loop calculate for 5 minutes, I have 3000 lines of binary the same width as your example, none of the outcomes had 3 in all columns... Before i put effort into this I want to be sure that the outcome is achievable, I'm guessing you won't want to leave the program running for longer than 5 minutes every press?

Comment: thank you @Glitch_Doctor. i will try later on. hope for the best result

Comment: Good luck, I ran it with 5 lines instead of 17 and it took 1 minute 34 seconds but the 17 lines was still not successful at the end of my shift yesterday - over 3 hours. If you find my answer succesful or helpful pelase remember to mark it as an answer - thank you. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: i just tried combine your coding and run, excel not responding. how can i fix? reduce the number of row?@Glitch_Doctor

Comment: when i try with a little data it can work. but with a lot data its cannot run @Glitch_Doctor

Comment: Sorry I have been ill for a while. It is a working code but there just aren't enough possible outcomes to run smoothly, only other thing I can think of is to save previous column outcomes in an array and get the script to avoid selecting those again. A lot of work though which I wont have time to attempt. Good luck!

Comment: hello @Glitch_Doctor . thank you so much. you help me a lot. btw, i have one problem which. i want to do like this but only with one column which column number 43 . can you help me? i try but it does not work.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand that last comment.

Comment: ohh sorry @Glitch_Doctor my bad. just forget it. i  have try and got one problem which is the range. how can i fix it?

Comment: no problem Jai. Perhaps edit your question with an update to show the problem that you are now facing and I can take a look at it. Specifically any errors that you are getting etc.

Comment: i think the coding is correct. but when i want to run it. excel suddenly not responding. how can i fix it?

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor see the previous comment

Comment: Probably because of the strain. Your code looks through each possible combination of binary. If the binary is 43 digits long (assumption as you stated column 43) then the possible outcomes: xⁿ where x is the number of possible outcomes per digit and ⁿ is the number of digits, 2^43 = 8,796,093,022,208... And that's without further limitation of the column totals. Not to mention your code doesn't store previous outcomes and can duplicate increasing this number further.

Comment: Anyway, SO isn't a free coding service, if you have errors you should update your code so that we can see what you have done and offer advice based on that. If I have answered your question please mark it as an answer and feel free to begin another thread relating to your other issue.

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve what you are looking for but the code will take a long time  to execute, I actually mocked up formula that mimics your code using `RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,"<>"&""))`  and `RandBetweenInt(1,COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,"<>"&""),***Range of Random Integers from above***)` (a user defined function found [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/157520-randbetween-excluding-values.html#)). This calculates much faster and does not include duplicate random figures.

```
Sub chkRand()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Do Until Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("I18").Value = 1
Application.Calculate
Loop

End Sub
```

`.Range("I18")` has the formula `=IF(COUNTIF(B18:H18,3)=7,1,0)` so this will force manual calculation and then recalculate until all of the columns total 3.

Be wary though I have left this macro running for 30minutes now and it still hasn't found a match.

Just in-case you were really looking for a VBA only solution I would use:

```
For Clm = 2 To 8
ClmTtl = 0
    For copyRow = 1 To percRows
     ClmTtl = ClmTtl + Sheets(1).Cells(MyRows(copyRow), clm).Value
    Next
    If Not ClmTtl = 3 Then Call Random20
Next
```

Though I would always advise seeking a formula based solution first and use macros only where they are required.

As this can only proceed to the next column when the previous one totals 3 the code can only finish when they all are of the desired total. Hope this helps, good luck reducing the runtime.